# Installing SQL Server R Services - error

Tags: r, sql-server-2016

I'm trying to Install SQL Server R Services.  I'm using SQL SERVER 2016 RC1.  I'm following this step by step tutorial https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt604883.aspx Everything seems to install ok, but I get the following error when testing an R script.

> Msg 39021, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>
> Unable to launch runtime for 'R' script. Please check the configuration of the 'R' runtime.
>
> Msg 39019, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>
> An external script error occurred: 
>   Unable to launch the runtime. ErrorCode 0x80070490: 1168(Element not found.).
>
> Msg 11536, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>
> EXECUTE statement failed because its WITH RESULT SETS clause specified 1 result set(s), but the statement only sent 0 result set(s) at run time.

I'm using the following code:

```
exec sp_execute_external_script  @language =N'r',
@script=N'OutputDataSet<-InputDataSet',  
@input_data_1 =N'select 1 as hello'
with result sets (([hello] int not null));
go
```

Any ideas as to what may be going wrong?

Thank You

Comment: I noticed that while the registerRext file says that it installs correctly, the dbrrerole does not exist. Also, the default file location for registerRext is a different path than what is provided in the directions.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue initially. I had mistakenly skipped the post-installation steps, specifically the step to register the R runtime with SQL Server. See MSDN post: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt590536.aspx

Comment: I ran the registerRext.exe as an administrator.  Still getting the same message.

Answer (score 0):

Try to uninstall using RegisterRext first and then install. Only this worked for me:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\R_SERVER\library\RevoScaleR\rxLibs\x64\RegisterRExt" /uninstall
```

Then

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\R_SERVER\library\RevoScaleR\rxLibs\x64\RegisterRExt" /install
```

Answer (score 0):

set User Account Control to never notify when apps try to install software or make changes to your computer.